# Content Type ID for folder in Office 365

Tags: office-365, 2016, nintex

I am trying to create a folder using Nintex

It asks for ContentType id and I gave 0x0120 as given [in MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452896(v=office.14).aspx)

[image]

But I got an error saying that

> The 'Content Type' specified is not found or not enabled in the
>   list/document library.

I am able to create folders in the library manually. What have I  missed?

P.S Though I am using this in Nintex, the error seems to be generic O365 error

Answer (score 1):

List/Library content types have different IDs than site content types.

It could be that Nintex is expecting the list content type ID, not the general Folder CT ID.  Create a folder in the destination library and look at its properties. In the query string you should see a `ContentTypeId` parameter. It will start with `0x0120`, then have two zeroes, and then a long string of characters after it. Try that value instead of `0x0120`.

Example: https://foobar.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=1&Source=https%3A%2F%2foobar%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2FShared%2520Documents%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&**ContentTypeId=0x012000534930A29DFAD44D87685FF4074B07A0**&RootFolder=%2FShared%20Documents